# Class 'BaklySystems\LaravelMessenger\LaravelMessengerServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, class, chat, hosting

I am developing a website on Laravel (both frontend and backend).

I installed the `baklysystems/laravel-chat-messenger` extension on my laptop project files, following every single installation step and it works fine. The chat works very well, I just made some style changes. However, when uploaded the files to GoDaddy hosting, I got the following error:

```
Class 'BaklySystems\LaravelMessenger\LaravelMessengerServiceProvider' not found

(1/1)Error
Class 'BaklySystems\LaravelMessenger\LaravelMessengerServiceProvider' not found
in ProviderRepository.php line 208
```

[image: Website homepage error]

Do any of you have any idea why is this happening?

Protip: I just uploaded the new files and made the modifications on the files that already where there, like for example including in `providers` in my `config/app.php` the line:

```
BaklySystems\LaravelMessenger\LaravelMessengerServiceProvider::class,
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please try `composer dump-autoload` or `composer update`

Comment: First I had to use `composer require baklysystems/laravel-chat-messenger` before using `composer dump-autoload`. Thank you very much!